# glassfish 4.0 admin console connection pool ping fails

Tags: glassfish-4, postgresql-9.3

With this error: Ping Connection Pool failed for postgreSQLPool. Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "/localhost:5432/mydatabase" does not exist

Pool configuration is as follows:

```
Pool Name: postgreSQLPool 
Resource Type: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
Datasource Classname: org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource
portNumber: 5432
databaseName: myDatabase
datasourceName: myDatabaseDS
roleName: myRole
networkProtocol: jdbc:postgresql:
serverName: //localhost
user: myUser
password: myPassword
```

The postgresql server is running because I can connect to the database using the same connection values as above.

postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar is in `$glassfish_home/domains/domain1/lib directory`

Any  help would be appreciated,

Dave

Comment: This error "*database "/localhost:5432/mydatabase" does not exist*" indicates that the JDBC URL is being created incorrectly. Otherwise the message would only be "*database "mydatabase" does not exist*"

Answer (score 1):

Your pool configuration looks wrong. `serverName` should not have `//` in it and `networkProtocol` is not for the JDBC URL.

Your config should look more like this:

```
Pool Name: postgreSQLPool 
portNumber: 5432
databaseName: myDatabase
datasourceName: myDatabaseDS
roleName: myRole
serverName: localhost
user: myUser
password: myPassword
```

(I'm not at all sure that `roleName` or `datasourceName` are needed or correct, but don't have time to further review the documentation to check).

If you still have problems, try falling back to the basic data source:

```
Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource
Datasource Classname: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
```

For info on the resource type, see [PGConnectionPoolDataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.html), [ConnectionPoolDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html).

See:

- [the docs on the `create-jdbc-connection-pool` console command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-jdbc-connection-pool-1.html)
- [this handy wiki entry for LifeRay which shows a sample config](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/PostgreSQL+with+Glassfish).

Answer (score 0):

Here:
 <DB_NAME>=myDatabase
 <DB_PORT>=5432
 <DB_USER>=myUser
 <DB_USER_PWD>=myPassword
 <SCHEMA_NAME>=mySchema
 <DB_CONN_POOL>=postgreSQLPool
 <DATA_SRC>=myDatabaseDS

**Procedure:**
a) Permit firewall glassfish server , postgres port, for example in centos7

```
#systemctl enable firewalld
#firewall --add-port=<DB_PORT>/tcp --permanent
##systemctl reload firewalld (<---doesn't work)
#firewall-cmd --reload
```

b) Configure pg_hba.conf for SSL login for the user:

```
hostnossl        all        all           0.0.0.0/0        reject
hostssl          all        postgres      0.0.0.0/0        reject
hostssl          <DB_NAME>  <USER_NAME>   <IR_ADDR>        md5
```

c) Create User, DB, Schema and grant previleges to the user, on required objects, for example:

```
###CREATE USER
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d postgres -c "CREATE USER <USER_NAME> ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'myUser_pwd';"
###CREATE DB
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE <DB_NAME> OWNER <USER_NAME> ENCODING 'UTF-8' TABLESPACE service_ts LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8' LIMIT -1;"
###CREATE SCHEMA
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d <DB_NAME> -c "CREATE SCHEMA "<SCHEMA_NAME>";"
###REVOKE PREVILEGES ON <SCHEMA_NAME> from public
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d <DB_NAME> -c "REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA "<SCHEMA_NAME>" FROM "public";"
###GRANT USAGE ON <SCHEMA_NAME> TO <DB_USER>
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d <DB_NAME> -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "<SCHEMA_NAME>" TO <USER_NAME>;"
###GRANT PREVILEGES ON TABLES OF <SCHEMA_NAME> TO <DB_USER>
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d <DB_NAME> -c "GRANT ALL ON TABLES IN SCHEMA "<SCHEMA_NAME>" TO <USER_NAME>;"
###GRANT PREVILEGES ON SEQUENCES OF <SCHEMA_NAME> TO <DB_USER>
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d <DB_NAME> -c "GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "<SCHEMA_NAME>" TO <USER_NAME>;"
###GRANT PREVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS OF <SCHEMA_NAME> TO <DB_USER>
sudo -u postgres psql -p <DB_PORT> -d <DB_NAME> -c "GRANT ALL ON FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA "<SCHEMA_NAME>" TO <USER_NAME>;"
```

d) Restart Postgresql to config changes take place
e) Place the correct postgresql jdbc4 jar (**corresponding to version of the server used eg. 9.3/9.4/10.1**) in the lib folder of the domain ((ie).../glassfish/domains/<DOMAIN_NAME>/lib)
f) Restart Glassfish to config changes take place

**use commands:**

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceClassName "org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource" --restype "javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" --property "ServerName=localhost:PortNumber=<DB_PORT>:DatabaseName=<DB_NAME>:User=<DB_USER>:Password=<DB_USER_PWD>" "<DB_CONN_POOL>"
```

and

```
asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid "<DB_CONN_POOL>" "jdbc/<DATA_SRC>"
```